# « À bientôt de te lire » en fin d'email

Tags: salutations, correspondance

La salutation « À bientôt de te lire » en fin d'email est-elle correcte ?

Je connaissais « au plaisir de te lire » mais pas celle-ci…

Google trouve [300.000 résultats](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%80%20bient%C3%B4t%20de%20te%20lire%22).

Comment: Surpris aussi, peut-être un régionalisme?

Comment: Je ne sais pas si c'est correct mais je l'emploie et je suis francophone de naissance. La notion de correction est une référence à une norme et là on va retomber dans le sempiternel débat de si oui ou non on accepte celle de l'académie française ! (à supposer que les immortels se soient prononcé là-dessus). Par ailleurs la « norme » dans les courriels est beaucoup plus détendue en ce qui concerne les salutations que dans des courriers papier et je ne pense pas que ce soit spécial au français.

Comment: Il n'y a qu'environ 500 résultats, ça s'arrête à la page 58… Google ne sait pas compter… Cela dit, je suis quand même surpris qu'il y en ait autant!

Comment: La réponse (que quelqu'un a plussoyée) de Laure suggère que cette expression est couramment utilisée par certains. Dans quelle(s) région(s) ?

Comment: Ce n'est absolument pas correct, pour moi c'est affreux !!!! et ça me choque !!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sans se soucier de l'avis de l'académie française, on peut se prononcer sur la correction d'une expression.

Celle-ci me semble tout simplement mal formée.
On peut s'attendre à ***dans l'attente*** de te lire ou ***dans l'espoir*** de te lire bientôt.
Mais la construction *A bientôt de [faire quelque chose]* n'a pas de sens.

Comment: Elle a un sens pour certains, puisqu'ils l'emploient, tout comme *à bientôt de te revoir* qui se dit aussi. Quant à dire que ce n'est pas correct, c'est l'éternel débat : qui décrète que ce n'est pas correct quand il n'y a pas de norme grammaticale ou lexicale ? S'il y en a une, je ne la connais pas.

Comment: *Dans l'espoir de lire* et *à bientôt de te lire* ne sont pas interchangeables :  
*dans l'espoir de lire* exprime un sentiment positif de la part du locuteur,  
*à bientôt de te lire* peut-être employé pour indiquer qu'on attend (voir pour faire pression sur le destinataire) une réponse sans que cela soit un plaisir de la recevoir.

Answer (score 4):

« Dans l'espoir de… » et « Au plaisir de… » signifient « **J'ai** l'espoir de… » et « **J'aurai** le plaisir de… »
On peut dire « J'aurai le plaisir de te lire. ».

En revanche, « À bientôt » ne donne aucune information sur le sujet **je**, uniquement sur le temps des retrouvailles. On pourrait dire « Au plaisir de te lire bientôt » (ou même, de manière plus poétique « Au plaisir, bientôt, de te lire »), ce qui signifie « J'aurai le plaisir de te lire bientôt » ; mais « À bientôt de te lire » signifierait « te lire bientôt », il manque clairement un sujet à cette phrase…

Answer (score 2):

Edit 29-02
Je viens de recevoir un courriel du chargé de communication d'une société commerciale, qui espère une réponse de ma part (mais ne peut l'exiger) se terminant par « À vous lire ».  Assez proche en construction que le « À  bientôt de te lire » du message originel.

Certains trouveraient ça « mal formé » et n'ayant « pas de sens ».  Mais ça se dit et ça ne me choque pas. Doit-on rejeter une expression qui est employée et comprise par tous sous prétexte qu'elle n'est pas bénie par l'académie ou les canons de la grammaire ? Qui fait la langue ? Une langue n'a-t-elle pas plus de chances de survivre déjà si on ne bloque pas son évolution ?

Comment: Si je reconnais la comprendre, je me dois d'ajouter que je tendrais à la corriger instantanément chez mon interlocuteur, tant elle me semble peu naturelle. *Qui fait la langue ?* Ce ne sont pas simplement les canons de la grammaire, une bonne majorité exprimée de natifs trouvent cette expression **très** étonnante, pour ne pas dire *fausse*. À moi, ça me fait furieusement penser à [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/3294/1514) et au *Toute autre forme sonnera vraiment bancal, voire carrément faux.* qu'elle s'est vite attirée. Régionalisme en mal de documentation, d'accord.

Comment: Un *À bientôt **pour** te lire* me choquerait (un peu) moins, par exemple, puisqu'il est (toujours trop) *tôt pour faire quelque chose*. Mais ça resterait bizarre à mes oreilles.

Answer (score 1):

C'est moins une question de droit, de convention, de règles, que celui de l'image que l'on veut donner de soi.

*A vous lire* reçu par Laure n'a rien de choquant pour quelqu'un d'attentif au sens des mots, on peut supposer que l'envoyeur aura "*plaisir* à vous lire" si vous prenez la peine de lui répondre par la même voie.

A bientôt *de quelque chose* perturbe la structure de la phrase, la construction sémantique et les autres habitudes.
Cela peut éventuellement être amical, un signe de proximité, ou dénoter un manquement plus sérieux si le reste des phrases est mal énoncé et témoigne d'une difficulté à concevoir clairement.

Les quantités relevées participent moins d'un rejet de toutes les règles que de l'abolition par le Web des barrières sociales, du respect des usages et des usagers qu'apportait la formulation écrite conventionnelle.

Je ne poursuivrais pas la lecture d'un message mercantile qui voudrait "*A bientôt de* me faire acheter ses merveilles."

Ce n'est donc pas pour ou contre la langue, c'est selon l'usage que l'on peut ou veut en faire.

Il peut être amusant d'enfreindre les règles que l'on connaît, parfois cela devient une licence poétique.