# Comment conjuguer ce qu'on tient pour acquis ?

Tags: conjugaison, néologismes, temps-grammatical, demande-de-mot

À l'oral, j'ai voulu exprimer l'idée « merci pour ce que, plus tard, tu auras fait », avec *me réveiller* comme quoi-faire.

J'ai donc commencé une phrase par « *Merci de me réveill…* » et n'ai pas su comment conjuguer, ni vraiment comment reformuler la phrase :

- sans dénaturer le sens ;
- de façon naturelle, et raisonnablement concise ;
- [audacieusement](http://www.evene.fr/citations/mot.php?mot=audace) si possible, *i.e.* néologismes bienvenus.

> *Quelle que soit la chose que l'on veut exprimer, il n'y a qu'un seul mot
>     pour l'exprimer, qu'un seul verbe pour l'animer, et qu'un adjectif pour la
>     qualifier.* Maupassant

**Je cherche ce mot-là.**

« *Merci de ce que tu me réveilleras.* » sonne un peu faux, mais c'est malheureusement ce que j'ai de mieux pour l'instant.

Comment: Note: Ce *quoi-faire* m'a l'air d'être un néologisme incompréhensible, il m'a fallu tout lire pour comprendre (avec effort) la première phrase.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : C'est pour donner le ton :·)

Comment: Tu cherches une langue avec des infinitifs futurs peut-être ? Ça existe, je pense à l'Espéranto par exemple.

Comment: Si on s'autorise les autres langues, alors ça n'a pas nécessairement besoin d'être un infinitif : il suffirait de remercier le processus inachevé qui commence par la promesse et qui s'achèvera par l'action effective. J'imagine que c'est plus facile à trouver, mais je n'en sais rien. Oui, ça m'intéresserait bien de savoir si/comment on peut dire ça dans d'autres langues. La [réponse d'un francophone](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/3297/1514) commence à expliquer pourquoi ça n'est pas possible en français, pour aller dans le même sens.

Comment: Ça devient alors une question pour [linguistics.se] :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je tente :

> Grâce à vous je peux m'endormir avec confiance, merci.

Deuxième essai :

> Grâce à toi, je me réveillerai avec joie. Merci !

Comment: Qui n'est pas sans mérite, mais qui pêche un peu du côté de l'oral, trouvé-je. Et puis, l'idée de réveil semble avoir pris la tangente.

Comment: Un edit permet de se réveiller, maintenant.

Comment: J'accepte l'alexandrin qui sui-rime, si l'edit passe.

Answer (score 3):

*Merci d'avoir accepté de me réveiller.* Utiliser autre chose qu'un infinitif après « merci de » semble bien trop audacieux et ne paraîtrait pas naturel. Il faut donc accepter d'utiliser un verbe non conjugué (éventuellement avec un aspect révolu comme ici), le sens de *accepter* transmet à lui seul l'idée de futur.

**Note:** Ceci était ma réponse, mais depuis que *audacieusement* à été ajouté à la question, je ne la comprends plus.

En changeant la préposition, on peut également penser à « Merci pour lorsque tu me réveilleras », ça ne sonne pas si faux que ça.

Comment: Sauf que… ce n'est pas le sens, je veux remercier de l'action, pas de la promesse.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse exprimer ça (remerciement pour une action qui n'a pas encore eu lieu) naturellement, et d'ailleurs je ne vois pas pourquoi on voudrait l'exprimer puisqu'on ne peut être certain de ce qui va arriver. Enfin pas dans ce monde-ci, peut-être dans d'[autres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_%28film%29).

Comment: D'où « *ce qu'on tient pour acquis* », auquel cas on **est** sûr de ce qui va arriver. Je prend *audacieux* méliorativement, d'où l'édit : c'est exactement ce que je cherche.

Answer (score 2):

L'infinitif présent s'emploie pour un fait présent ou futur. (Grevisse, douzième édition, paragraphe 864).  Le problème n'est donc pas de nature grammaticale mais lexicale, *merci* pour un fait futur sonne comme une requête plus ou moins impérative et non un remerciement.  Il faut donc changer la formulation, mais je crains que toute formulation axée directement sur le fait futur va partager la caractéristique qui rend les constructions basées sur *merci* inadéquates, on aura au final quelque chose qui sonnera comme un ordre plus ou moins poli.

Comment: Je conçois le diagnostic, et le déplore. Pourtant, le « *pour lorsque* » de Stéphane est bien trouvé, je ne renonce pas.

Answer (score 0):

Si l'action n'a pas encore eu lieu:

> Merci de me réveiller

Si elle a déjà eu lieu:

> Merci de m'avoir réveillé

Toute autre forme sonnera vraiment bancal, voire carrément faux.

Mais tout comme Stéphane dans sa réponse, j'avoue ne pas trop comprendre le but de la question...

Comment: L'action n'a pas encore eu lieu. Le problème est que « *Merci de me réveiller* » sonne comme une prière, plutôt que comme un remerciement. Le but de la question ? **Exprimer précisément l'idée décrite**, pour le coup je ne sais pas comment le dire différement… Je vais rajouter une citation.

Comment: Ce que vous voulez exprimer, c'est remercier quelqu'un pour une action qu'il accomplira, ou au moins qu'il a promis/accepté d'accomplir? Dans ce cas, le *Merci d'avoir accepté de me réveiller* de Stéphane est effectivement ce qui se rapproche le plus de l'idée...